# Error in if (max_y < 0.75) max_y = 0.75 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I would like to plot a ggplot with these data, but I keep getting the error

```
"Error in if (max_y < 0.75) max_y = 0.75 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

Below are my data (i.e.,it is called the `cumtable`):

```
         X1           X2
cummean   1          NaN
X         2          NaN
X.1       3          NaN
X.2       4  0.085958396
X.3       5  0.579000051
X.4       6          NaN
X.5       7  0.828634359
X.6       8          NaN
X.7       9          NaN
X.8      10  0.286389237
X.9      11  0.060052680
X.10     12          NaN
X.11     13  0.523594292
X.12     14  0.114135103
X.13     15          NaN
X.14     16          NaN
X.15     17          NaN
X.16     18          NaN
X.17     19  0.740793870
X.18     20  0.709364041
X.19     21  0.483116357
X.20     22          NaN
X.21     23          NaN
X.22     24  0.995054034
X.23     25  0.783238116
X.24     26          NaN
X.25     27          NaN
X.26     28  0.578728321
X.27     29  1.023346667
X.28     30  0.777934859
X.29     31  0.898343165
X.30     32  0.484138182
X.31     33  0.074883785
X.32     34  0.430788239
X.33     35  0.483925567
X.34     36          NaN
X.35     37  0.484475666
X.36     38          NaN
X.37     39  0.428624931
X.38     40  0.098168286
X.39     41          NaN
X.40     42  0.923720114
X.41     43  0.891545077
X.42     44  0.557582982
X.43     45  0.162431464
X.44     46  0.698346912
X.45     47  0.963385003
X.46     48  0.130043928
X.47     49  0.777339044
X.48     50  0.188371148
X.49     51          NaN
X.50     52  0.969137929
X.51     53  0.083899745
X.52     54  0.110960336
X.53     55          NaN
X.54     56          NaN
X.55     57          NaN
X.56     58  0.770282794
X.57     59          NaN
X.58     60  0.495483189
X.59     61  0.466880181
X.60     62  0.915412418
X.61     63  0.340461942
X.62     64  0.284567410
X.63     65          NaN
X.64     66  0.764779562
X.65     67  9.021032202
X.66     68  0.717319265
X.67     69          NaN
X.68     70  0.660980523
X.69     71  0.278495425
X.70     72  0.327933658
X.71     73  0.415319194
X.72     74  0.605468929
X.73     75  0.636267888
X.74     76  0.610612250
X.75     77  0.848616067
X.76     78          NaN
X.77     79  0.524346792
X.78     80  0.858387070
X.79     81          NaN
X.80     82  0.885703729
X.81     83  0.571135262
X.82     84  0.363989504
X.83     85 -0.003483148
X.84     86          NaN
X.85     87          NaN
X.86     88  0.604364690
X.87     89          NaN
X.88     90 -1.485618961
X.89     91          NaN
X.90     92  0.790697810
X.91     93          NaN
X.92     94  0.670599183
X.93     95  0.082025677
X.94     96          NaN
X.95     97  0.618979367
X.96     98          NaN
X.97     99  0.570178950
X.98    100          NaN
```

Here're my codes:

```
trial1 = cumtable
max_y = ceiling(max(trial1$X2))
if (max_y < .75) max_y = .75 
min_y = floor(min(trial1$X2))
if (min_y > .4) min_y = .4
last_mean = round(trial1[nrow(trial),2],9)

plot1 = ggplot(trial1, aes(x=index,y=cum_mean)) +
geom_line(colour = "blue") +
geom_abline(intercept=0.5,slope=0, color = 'red', size=.5) +      
theme(plot.title = element_text(size=rel(1.5)),
      panel.background = element_rect()) +
labs(x = "n (number of tosses)", 
     y = "Cumulative Average") +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min_y, max_y)) +
scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10",
                   breaks = trans_breaks("log10",function(x) 10^x),
                   labels = trans_format("log10",math_format(10^.x))) +
annotate("text",
         label=paste("Cumulative mean =", last_mean,
                     "\nEV =",  prob,
                     "\nSample size =", nflip), 
         y=(max_y - .20), 
         x=10^(log10(nflip)/2), colour="darkgreen") +
annotate("text",
       label=paste("P(Heads)=", prob), 
       y=(max_y - .80), 
       x=10^(log10(nflip)/2), colour="red")
```

I thought it is because of the `last_mean = round(trial1[nrow(trial),2],9)` (line 6) , so I removed this line but still getting the same error.

I also tried to remove all the row with NA but I still get the same error, and I am worried that I will get a discrete plot. I don't want to remove any of the NAs but rather replace them as unfilled dots in the ggplot.

**Goals:**

1. successfully graph the ggplot with the data,
2. the NaN will show up as unfilled dot on the ggplot.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a column called `index` in your data

Comment: @Mako212 , right! thank you!

Comment: but I now got another error in if (max_y < 0.75) max_y = 0.75 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Answer (score 0):

I usually find any error like `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` to usually mean that whatever variable or expression is put in parenthesis of an `if ()` to strictly not be a TRUE or FALSE value.

Right now you have something like  `if (max_y < .75)` but it's evaluating to something like  `if (NA < .75)`, which in turn is `if(NA)`, which isn't allowed.

I think your second line of code: `max_y = ceiling(max(trial1$X2))` would not evaluate to a NA if you changed it t o `max_y = ceiling(max(trial1$X2, na.rm = TRUE))`.  Then your `max_y` will successfully be a number and work.